# EL get value of a HashMap by Integer key

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have this HashMap:

```
    Map<Integer, String> odometerMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
    odometerMap.put(0, getLocaleForKey("drop-down.any"));
    odometerMap.put(1, "< 1000");
    odometerMap.put(2, "1000 - 5000");
    odometerMap.put(3, "5000 - 10000");
    odometerMap.put(4, "10000 - 20000");
    odometerMap.put(5, "20000 - 30000");
    odometerMap.put(6, "30000 - 40000");
    odometerMap.put(7, "40000 - 60000");
    odometerMap.put(8, "60000 - 80000");
    odometerMap.put(9, "> 80000");
```

My goal in JSP is to print for example ${odometerMap[2]} (result is empty string):

```
    <c:out value="${odometerMap[2]}"/>
```

If I print only ${odometerMap} I get the full map:

```
{0=Any, 1=< 1000, 2=1000 - 5000, 3=5000 - 10000, 4=10000 - 20000, 5=20000 - 30000, 6=30000 - 40000, 7=40000 - 60000, 8=60000 - 80000, 9=> 80000}
```

How can I print only an element of my choice? Ex: 2?

Thank you

Comment: Is *odometerMap* a scoped (page,request,session,application) object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In EL, numbers are treated as `Long`. It's looking for a `Long` key. It'll work if you use `Long` instead of `Integer` as map key.

```
Map<Long, String> odometerMap = new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>();
odometerMap.put(0L, getLocaleForKey("drop-down.any"));
odometerMap.put(1L, "< 1000");
// ...
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative could be using a `String` as the key

```
Map<String, String> odometerMap;
```

.. and:

```
<c:out value="${odometerMap['2']}"/>
```

But, it's better to use a `List` of `Strings` since your key doesn't have any clear meaning:

```
List<String> odometers = new ArrayList<String>();
odometers.add(getLocaleForKey("drop-down.any"));
// etc
```

.. and:

```
<c:out value="${odometers[2]}"/>
```