# Passing Map to JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC / JSP world. Sorry if below problem is obvious,

I've a map `Map<BigInteger, String> reports = new HashMap<>();` that needs to be passed to JSP from controller. 
The content of map will be like this

```
reports.put(new BigInteger("101"), "type1");
reports.put(new BigInteger("102"), "type2");
reports.put(new BigInteger("103"), "type3");
```

From Spring MVC controller I'm passing this map as below:

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("view");
mav.addObject("reports", reports);
```

But when I'm trying to access this in **view.jsp** with below scriplet:-

```
<% String a1 = request.getAttribute("reports").get(new BigInteger("101")); %>
```

But this gives me the following exception:

```
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method get(java.math.BigInteger)
  location: class java.lang.Object
```

Same exception if I tried to get the value using Expression as below:-

```
<%= request.getAttribute("reports").get(new BigInteger("101")) %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.getAttribute("reports")` returns reference of `Object` not of `Map`, you will have to *cast* it

you better go for JSTL to avoid java code in view template

Answer (score 2):

As Jigar Joshi stated, you'll need to cast in order to access the map in the JSP

```
<%= ((Map<BigInteger, String>) request.getAttribute("reports")).get(new BigInteger("101")) %>
```

However as also stated, it would be cleaner to use an EL expression. As the map is keyed by `BigInteger` you'd need to convert the keys to either `String` or `Long` so they are [accessible to EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247806/jstl-get-value-of-a-hashmap-by-key-integer).

With a `String` key:

```
reports.put("101", "type1");
```

in the JSP you can use:

```
<c:out value="${reports['101']}"/>
```

or with a `Long` key:

```
reports.put(101L, "type1");
```

you can use:

```
<c:out value="${reports[101]}"/>
```