# EL Collection#contains not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat7, el

I am working in a Spring, JSP, Tomcat environment with servlet version 3.0. I am trying to use the `Collection#contains` method (that I understand was added to servlet 3.0). It doesn't seem to be working, and in debugging, I have come up with the following strange case which seems to pinpoint the problem:

```
${priority[0] == 1}
${priority[0] eq 1}
${priority.contains(priority[0])}
${priority.contains(1)}
```

This prints out

`true true true false`

Also, `priority` is a `List<Integer>` that contains the integers `1,2,3`.

So, the question is, how/why does that last check print `false`?

EDIT to respond to comment: Yes the list contains `1` when called from within the Intellij debugger.

Comment: In the last case, try casting it to an Integer, I bet there is a problem when inputting an int when it expects an object.

Comment: And do you have the same problem in regular java, when you aren't in a jsp file?

Comment: @jwill if that's true than `${priority[0] == 1}` this should also fail but it does not.

Comment: This is technically a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12247806 By the way, this all has nothing to do with `Collection#contains()` being added to Servlet 3.0 (it exist already since Java 1.2), but it's just the new EL 2.2 feature of being able to invoke non-getter methods using `method()` syntax with parentheses.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks that makes sense. So, why doesn't the `==` comparison fail?

Comment: Because `priority[0]` is widened to `long`. See also [EL 2.2 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/expression_language-2.2-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/expression_language-2_2-mrel-spec.pdf)  chapter 1.8.2 "A {==,!=,eq,ne} B" point "If A or B is Byte, Short, Character, Integer, or Long coerce both A and B to
Long, apply operator"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a small class:

```
public static class Test {
    public String contains(Object value) {
        return value.getClass().toString();
    }
}
```

Added it to as a JSP attribute called `test`, then:

```
${test.contains(1)}
```

Generates:

```
class java.lang.Long
```

`Long` is not an `Integer`, so not found in `List<Integer>`.

---

**Update**

The following was run on Tomcat 8, and won't work as-is on older versions, but serves to illustrate that a non-float literal is a `Long`, not an `Integer` (a float literal is `Double`), but that `==` still does numeric comparison, so *Long value == Integer value* works correctly.

```
${test.contains(1)}
${test.contains(Long.valueOf('1'))}
${test.contains(Integer.valueOf('1'))}
${Long.valueOf('1') == Integer.valueOf('1')}
```

Generates:

```
class java.lang.Long
class java.lang.Long
class java.lang.Integer
true
```

Comment: Noted should be that the examples in your update section doesn't work on Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2, but only on Servlet 3.1 / EL 3.0. Only since EL 3.0 classes of the `java.lang.*` package are implicitly imported in EL scope. So this code will fail in OP's case with Tomcat 7.

Comment: Your reasoning for `==` is incorrect/incomplete. See my comment on the question.

Comment: @BalusC You are correct, "numeric comparison" is *super shorthand* for the very long description of what JSP actually does.

Comment: There's ambiguity because EL actually uses `Object#equals()` when applying the `==` operator. This obviously fails when applied on `Integer` and `Long`. So, your reasoning is incorrect when considering that `Object#equals()` is being used. Note that this all is not done by JSP, but by EL. Well, that comment contains a link. If you're curious, go read it :)

Comment: Not to start a long discussion, but I meant that my phrase "numeric comparison" was meant as doing a comparison of the numbers, not the objects, which JSP EL does by following the logic defined in section 1.8.2 (thanks for the link). It *works* for `Integer` and `Long` because `Integer` is coerced to `Long`. Where JSP EL got it wrong is for `BigDecimal` because `1.0 == 1.00`, `1.0 < 1.00`, and `1.0 > 1.00` are all `false`!