# EL method call for displaying data in datatable

Tags: jsf-2, hashmap, el

I wonder that it isn't possible to display data in JSF 2.0 (with Tomcat 8 and El-impl 2.2) using EL bean method call.
I have a Map. A key is an ID of Dish and a value - quantity. I need to show the name of each dish in Map and its quantity, but I cannot do it via getNameOfDish(Integer id) method, where id is dish ID - I receive

```
javax.el.ELException: /KitchenStaff-Main.xhtml @42,67 value="#{o`rderBean.getNameOfDish(item.key)}": Method not found
```

My bean is:

```
@Named
@Scope("session")
public class OrderBean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<OrderItems> listForCook;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> mapOfChief;
...
@PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        mapOfChief = new HashMap<>();
        listForCook = kitchStaff.viewItems();
        for(OrderItems e: listForCook){
            mapOfChief.put(e.getId(), e.getQuantity());
        }
    }
public String getNameOfDish(Integer id){
        for(OrderItems e: listForCook){
            if(e.getDish().getId()==id){
                return e.getDish().getName();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
...
```

xhtml page snippet:

```
...
<h:form>
                <p:dataTable value="#{orderBean.mapOfChief.entrySet().toArray()}"
                    var="item">

                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">#{msg['admin.NameOfDish']}</f:facet> 
                    <h:outputText value="#{orderBean.getNameOfDish(item.key)}"/> 
                    </p:column>
...
```

Is there any another way to get dish name except creating new variable with getter/setter and initialize it each time with getNameOfDish method?

Comment: Does this also apply on you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247806/el-get-value-of-a-hashmap-by-integer-key

Comment: Thanks for a reply! Not actually: my aim is to display all map, but instead of a raw map key Integer id, utilise it for method findDishNameById(Integer id) invocation. However, now I amn't sure whether it's possible to call bean method during iteration with var="" inside JSF.

Comment: So you're saying that your problem still isn't solved if you change map from `Map<Integer, Integer>` to `Map<Long, Integer>` and `getNameOfDish(Integer)` to `(Long)` as explained in the answer?

Comment: Have to acknowledge that on the first view I didn't found your approach applicable in my case due to the use of it in jsp. I was my fault - I've made the corrections mentioned by you and everything works fine now. Thanks for the patience and excuse me for inconveniences.